# OpenID Authentication Method Reference Name for a code sent via email

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, openid

**Introduction:**

I am currently implementing `acr_values`, `acr` & `amr` principles on a Open ID Provider server.

The claim `amr` (described in the [OpenID RFC 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)) has no standard clearly defined in this same RFC, but I would like to base the system on the [RFC 8176](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8176#section-2) mentioned by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/authentication-method-reference-values/authentication-method-reference-values.xhtml).

One of the server authentication method is about sending a confirmation code via email.

**About the authentication method:**

The server uses a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator and store a hash of it using argon2.
It is sent to an email, then hash are compared on another request. There is a short expiration time for each code.
This method is indeed not considered by the server as a secure method to prove an identity, but is still selectable when no access to any resource is required.

The question is:

**What Authentication Method Reference Name would you use in this case ?**

Most descriptions are quite strict so I only see `mca` as a possibility today. It is not an `otp` to me since it is not implementing the [RFC 4226](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4226).

Thanks for sharing.